FacetWP preselect choices on refresh
I have a page that gets all posts from a custom post type.
On this page are several facets.
One is the "main" facet that switches between categories of the post types.
One of the other facet is the dates related to each post.
I managed to have a preselect of the first category and first related date with the following code:
 function preselect_facets($url_vars)
{
  if (false !== strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'programme')) { // Check if 'programme' is in the URI
    global $wpdb;

    // Preselect the first available value for the `categories` facet
    if (empty($url_vars['categories'])) {
      $first_category = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT DISTINCT facet_value
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}facetwp_index
        WHERE facet_name = %s
        ORDER BY facet_display_value ASC
        LIMIT 1
      ", 'categories'));

      if ($first_category) {
        $url_vars['categories'] = [$first_category]; // Set the preselected value
      }
    }

    // Preselect the first available value for the `conference_dates` facet
    if (!empty($url_vars['categories']) && empty($url_vars['conference_dates'])) {
      $category_value = esc_sql($url_vars['categories'][0]); // Use the selected category

      $first_date = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT DISTINCT cd.facet_value
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}facetwp_index cd
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}facetwp_index cat ON cd.post_id = cat.post_id
        WHERE cd.facet_name = %s
          AND cat.facet_name = %s
          AND cat.facet_value = %s
          AND cd.facet_display_value != ''
        ORDER BY cd.facet_display_value ASC
        LIMIT 1
      ", 'conference_dates', 'categories', $category_value));

      if ($first_date) {
        $url_vars['conference_dates'] = [$first_date];
      }
    }
  }
  return $url_vars;
}

add_filter('facetwp_preload_url_vars', 'preselect_facets');

This works fine on the first page load, but not when the facetwp triggers a refresh, for instance if the main category changes.
Is there a specific filter that I could use in order to trigger this pre-selection on refresh ?
